# Regular expression gawk matching

Tags: regex, gawk

I'm using gawk in terminal to match the `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []` line in the file below. I'm using `gawk '$1 ~ /ALLOWED_HOSTS =.+$/{ print $0 }' file_name`. I don't get any matching. It's very puzzling. I've tried using `/^ALLOWED_HOSTS =.+$/`, but got no success. Please see the near the end of the text to see the line I'm trying to match.

```
Django settings for superlists project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '4(8f0buww1_&0jqmo-zg89$!epi=zd0)z3v^d+qp&z63fg*bin'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition
```

Comment: What is the FS(FieldSeperator) you are using? By default " "(space) is the FS. so matching with $1 might be the issue here. /^ALLOWED_HOSTS[[:space:]]+=.+$/{print } might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` only contains the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` token, not the rest of the line. You want to compare against `$0` -- which is implied anyway if you don't supply a specific value to compare against, so your entire script is equivalent to

```
gawk '/ALLOWED_HOSTS/' file_name
```